# Tensorflow API Ubuntu Error

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tensorflow, object-detection

```
python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/train_labels.csv --output_path=data/train.record
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 20, in <module>
    from utils import dataset_util
ImportError: cannot import name dataset_util
```

I have import problem 
Full code is here
https://hastebin.com/inolutefip.py

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect **code** to be **in the question post** itself (as text), not linked. Please, [edit] the question and make appropriate corrections. For format the code you may use `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button while the code is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a PYTHONPATH to the `object_detection` folder.  The file is trying to import the `dataset_util` file from the `research/object_detection/util` folder.  Seting a PYTHONPATH varies by operating system.

The below link contains Ubuntu oriented instructions for the TensorFlow Object Detection API:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#add-libraries-to-pythonpath

The below link contains Windows oriented instructions for the TensorFlow Object Detection API:
https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10#2e-configure-pythonpath-environment-variable